# Curl Error: unable to set private key file: 'test.pem' type PEM

Tags: php, ssl, curl

My Pem file is in this format.

```
Bag Attributes
localKeyID:
friendlyName: test
subject=/C=GB/ST=London/L=Soho/O=Rightmove/OU=RTDF/CN=cmexpertise
issuer=/C=GB/ST=London/L=Soho/O=Rightmove/OU=Operations/CN=RTDF Test Issuing CA v3/emailAddress=operations@rightmove.co.uk
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Bag Attributes
localKeyID:
friendlyName: test
subject=/C=GB/ST=London/L=Soho/O=Rightmove/OU=RTDF/CN=cmexpertise
issuer=/C=GB/ST=London/L=Soho/O=Rightmove/OU=Operations/CN=RTDF Test Issuing CA v3/emailAddress=operations@rightmove.co.uk
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Bag Attributes
localKeyID:
friendlyName: test
subject=/C=GB/ST=London/L=Soho/O=Rightmove/OU=RTDF/CN=cmexpertise
issuer=/C=GB/ST=London/L=Soho/O=Rightmove/OU=Operations/CN=RTDF Test Issuing CA v3/emailAddress=operations@rightmove.co.uk
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,B9E036426B7AEDA6
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm using this code of PHP. I'm getting this error.

> Curl Error: unable to set private key file: 'test.pem' type PEM

Code.

```
   $json_data  // it's a json array.

    $url = "https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // $pemFile = tmpfile();
    // fwrite($pemFile, "test.pem");   //the path for the pem file
    // $tempPemPath = stream_get_meta_data($pemFile);
    // $tempPemPath = $tempPemPath['uri'];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "test.pem"); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,"PEM");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/javascript'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo "Curl Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Success: ". $result;
    }

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler

    if (empty($info['http_code'])) {
            die("No HTTP code was returned"); 
    } else {
        // load the HTTP codes
        $http_codes = parse_ini_file("path/to/the/ini/file/I/pasted/above");

        // echo results
        echo "The server responded: <br />";
        echo $info['http_code'] . " " . $http_codes[$info['http_code']];
    }
```

I check online for certificate decoder : 
https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html
and certificate is valid on this site.

So what is the problem here i can't figure it out. 
I tried with ssl command also.

Comment: Curl Error: could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0200107B:system library:fopen:Unknown error, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?).This is the error I get when I use your php code and pem file. The reason being  the private key in that file does not match the corresponding public key in the certificate.

Comment: @Reddy. Thank you for your reply brother. there are two errors one error was of pem file there is a error in pem file and another error is i didn't include CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD()  in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors.

- one error was of pem file there is a error in pem file generation.
- another error is i didn't include CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD() in code.

Code,

```
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,"PEM");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "test.pem");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, '******'); // password
```